# How to run multiple datetimepickers on the same page?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker

There are a lot of date and time plugins for jQuery, but it seems that there is a problem when trying to run more than one instance of this plugin.

My code:

```
    //date and time
    $('.datepick').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        language: 'nb',
        weekStart: 1,
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    }); 

    $('.timepick').timepicker({
        minuteStep: 15,
        showInputs: false,
        disableFocus: true,
        showMeridian: false
    });
```

Some html:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
<label class="text-muted">Date</label>
<div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datepick" name="date">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"></i></span>
</div>
```

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="text-muted">TIME</label>
    <div class="input-group date">
        <input type="text" class="form-control timepick" name="time">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-lg"></i></span>
    </div>                  
</div>
```

I have a script that copies this code when I click a add button; the issue is that the datetimepickers won't work on the fields added to the form.

Does anyone have pointers how to make the datetimepickers show on all inputfileds that have the class datepick/timepick?

**UPDATE**
Seams this code did the trick.

```
    $("body").delegate("input[type=text].datepick", "focusin", function(){
          $('.datepick').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            language: 'nb',
            weekStart: 1,
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        }); 
    }); 

    $("body").delegate("input[type=text].timepick", "focusin", function(){
        $('.timepick').timepicker({
            minuteStep: 15,
            showInputs: false,
            disableFocus: true,
            showMeridian: false
        });
    });
```

Comment: Did you remember to initialize the picker code again after adding the HTML elements?

Comment: that's because you are calling date/time pickers on document ready and this is ok. If you add some elements after the document has been rendered in the browser these elements will not respond to the document.ready functions. You need to use jQuery delegated events using .on and binding to a parent element that exists on dom ready

Comment: Your script should reinitialize the code.

Comment: I have the code running in a <script> tag, but i dont have any re-initializeing in my code.

Comment: @sdfgg45 Your edit is what I was talking about! Two things: better to use `.on` than `.delegate` (syntax is the same) and also try to see if there is a closer parent (like a container div) that is already there at document ready instead of using body that is a too much wide scope